# I have a license number on my screen all the time on Windows 11 (which is on an officially bought laptop). How can I hide it?

Tags: windows

I have a license number on my screen all the time on Windows 11 (which is on an officially bought laptop). How can I hide it?

My unhelpful Google search:
https://www.google.com/search?q=I+have+a+license+number+on+my+screen+all+the+time+on+Windows+11+(which+is+on+an+officially+bought+laptop).+How+can+I+hide+it%3F&oq=I+have+a+license+number+on+my+screen+all+the+time+on+Windows+11+(which+is+on+an+officially+bought+laptop).+How+can+I+hide+it%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.1038j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Screenshot of what you are seeing please.

Comment: Sounds like a company device that’s been configured with bginfo, a complete clean install of Windows 11, is the simplest solution. **Only do this with authorization from the device owner.**

Comment: Easier: run BGInfo (probably as Admin), clear all info displayed, and save. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8d3f534-9a99-4a3c-b385-8c7a065c4b81/how-to-remove-bginfo-from-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Funny story - it was a transparent protective film on the screen. My interlocutor had not seen the aforementioned numbers, which pushed me to that guess; I put off the film and the guess was confirmed. A long time ago those films were without any writings.